# How to run windows command using python

Tags: python, cmd

This is the code :

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

thisDir = Path("C:/Users/91883/Downloads/Telegram Desktop")

for r, d, f in os.walk(thisDir):
    for file in f:
        if file.endswith('mkv'):
            arg =  os.path.join(Path("C:/Program Files/MKVToolNix/mkvpropedit.exe"), Path(f' {thisDir}/{file} -e info -s title=""'))
            os.popen(arg)
```

Basically, I want to run this cmd:
`"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvpropedit.exe" "C:\Users\91883\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\file.mkv" -e info -s title=""`

Comment: Construct the user and executable path with `os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + '/Downloads/Telegram Desktop'` and `os.environ['ProgramFiles']`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run commands using Python, you can use this os.system() function.

```
os.system("Enter your command here.")
```

Comment: is.system() takes str as argument, but I'm trying to run argument of type PATH, coverting PATH in to str is pain, because windows uses backslash and combined with directory name with spaces it is more painful to convert into str.